# WCF extensions execution order

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-extensions

If i have few WCF extension modules of same kind (like parameter inspector) can i be sure they're executed in the order i define them in the configuration file?

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="MyInspectorA" type="blabla" />
            <add name="MyInspectorB" type="blabla" />
        </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I need more guaranties than just my observations but can't find any confirmations on MSDN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They'll be executed in the order they appear in the

`<system.serviceModel> 
    <behaviors> 
        <[service|endpoint]Behaviors> 
          <behavior>
            <behavior_1 />
            <behavior_2 />
            <behavior_n />
          </behavior>
        </[service|endpoint]Behaviors> 
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>`

, not in the order listed in the behavior extensions.

And service behaviors are called before endpoint behaviors - the order among the behaviors is described in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/16/wcf-extensibility-behaviors.aspx.

Comment: hmmm that document does not really support your assertion. I have also read that amongst service behaviours there is no guarantee of order of execution.